# Passing Two dimensional array to C++ using command line

Tags: c++, arrays, command-line

I am having a requirement where in I need to call a C++ application from command line and need to pass a two dimensional array of int type to it. Can anyone please let me know how to do that, and how to interpret it in C++ application using argv parameter

thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be easier to provide the array on stdin.

Answer (score 6):

In `argv` you can pass only a one dimensional array, containing strings, it's

```
char* argv[]
```

So, you can't really pass 2D array, but you can "simulate" it.

For example, pass 2 parameters, saying what are the sizes of the matrix - number of rows and number of columns and then pass all elements, one by one.

Then parse the arguments in your program, knowing what format you will use.

---

For example: if you want to pass

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

you may run your program like this:

```
./my_program 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

This way, you'll know, that `argv[1]` is the number of rows, `argv[2]` s the number of columns and them all elements of the 2D array, starting from the upper left corner.

Don't forget, that `argv` is array, containing `char*` pointers. In other words, you'll need to convert all parameters `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend passing a file as the only argument. Or data in the same format on stdin as @j_random_hacker suggests. If no human needs to edit it, it could be a binary file. One possible format:

4 bytes = size of first dimension
4 bytes = size of second dimension
4 bytes * size of first * size of second = contents of array

When reading, everything is aligned. Just read every four byte int and interpret as above.

If it needs to be human readable I would do csv or space-delimited. There would be no need to specify the dimensions in that case because each row ends in newline.