# Integer and a filename as two command-line arguments in C

Tags: c

I want to send the size of an 2D array and filename as command line arguments in C.

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
```

I know this works for single arguments, but how do I take two arguments?

Comment: It should work for multiple arguments as well, argc will have the count and argv is an array of values.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156514/passing-two-dimensional-array-to-c-using-command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `argc` tells you the number of arguments.
- `argv` is an array of char pointers to c-style strings.

So you can simply print all arguments by:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
     int i;
     for (i=0; i<argc; ++i)
     {
         printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
     }
}
```

You can use `atoi` to convert (the initial portion of) a string to an integer.

So you can do something like:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) 
{
     char filename[100];
     int size = 0;
     int i;
     if (argc < 3)
     {
         printf("Too few arguments\n");
         return 0;
     }
     if (strlen(argv[1]) >= 100)
     {
         printf("File name too long\n");
         return 0;
     }
     strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
     size = atoi(argv[2]);
     if (size <= 0)
     {
         printf("Invalid size\n");
         return 0;
     }

     ....
     ....

     return 0;
}
```

Note that it is usually not necessary to copy file name arguments to another variable unless you are going to modify the value in some way.

Comment: Could also use `strtol()` for integer conversion. Provides error checking, whereas `atoi()` doesn't.